# First ios application giving blank white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting black screen when i initially run on my iphone.When i disconnect my iphone from my mac and open the applications a plain white screen opens.Please Help.

BNRQuizTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BNRQuizTableViewController.h"


@interface BNRQuizTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

BNRQuizTableViewController.m

```
#import "BNRQuizTableViewController.h"

@interface BNRQuizTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) int currentQuestionIndex;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *questions;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *answers;

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;

@end

@implementation BNRQuizTableViewController
-(IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender
{
 {
    // Step to the next question
    self.currentQuestionIndex++;

    // Am I past the last question?
    if (self.currentQuestionIndex == [self.questions count])
    {

        // Go back to the first question
        self.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    }

    // Get the string at that index in the questions array
    NSString *question = self.questions[self.currentQuestionIndex];

    // Display the string in the question label
    self.questionLabel.text = question;
    self.answerLabel.text=@"???";
 }
}

-(IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender
{
 {
    // What is the answer to the current question?
    NSString *answer = self.answers[self.currentQuestionIndex];

    // Display it in the answer label
    self.answerLabel.text = answer;
 }

}



- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
                     bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
// Call the init method implemented by the superclass
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self)
 {
    // Create two arrays filled with questions and answers
    // and make the pointers point to them

    self.questions = @[@"What is the name of the first prophet?",
                       @"What is the name of the last prophet",
                       @"Who was the first caliph ?"];

    self.answers = @[@"Prophet Adam(A.S)",
                     @"Propher Mohammed(S.A.W)",
                     @"Hazrat Abu bakar"];
 }

// Return the address of the new object
return self;
}


@end;
```

BNRAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BNRAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

BNRAppdelegate.m

```
#import "BNRAppDelegate.h"
#import "BNRQuizTableViewController.h"



@implementation BNRAppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

BNRQuizTableViewController *quizvc = [[BNRQuizTableViewController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController=quizvc;


self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why do you have extra `{ }` on the `showQuestion:` and `showAnswer:` methods? And could it possibly be a white screen because you set it to be white on this line `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` this is in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. As far as this code shows you don't have any interface.

Comment: The extra brackets have been corrected then too problem persistThe interface i have made using interface builder(XIB file).I have used drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the nib name for your view controller with `initWithNibName:bundle:` otherwise the view controller will have no valid view assigned:

```
BNRQuizTableViewController *quizvc = [[BNRQuizTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"YOUR_NIB_NAME_HERE" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: after specifying nib name i am getting this exception.Please Help       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Did you setup your nib correctly? Did you set `BNRQuizTableViewController` as File`s Owner and did you connect the `view` property?